# Python overriding of property does not work

Tags: python, inheritance, properties

In the code below I would expect that it shouldn't matter if I use the property `val` or call the function `get_val`. The output should be the same.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

class A():
    def get_val(self):
        print(self)
        raise NotImplementedError

    val = property(get_val)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b_val = "foo\n"

    def get_val(self):
        print(self)
        return self.b_val

b = B()
print(b.get_val())
print(b.val)
```

But the output I get is:

```
<__main__.B object at 0x0000014BD2BBE898>
foo

<__main__.B object at 0x0000014BD2BBE898>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prop_override_test.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(b.val)
  File "prop_override_test.py", line 6, in get_val
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

Why doesn't the property use the overriden `get_val` function?

I use python version 3.6.2

```
python --version
Python 3.6.2
```

Comment: You don't override `val` in `B`, so it still uses `A.val` which is `property(A.get_val)`

Comment: Because `val` is in class A and is bound to A.get_val().  That is, it is bound to a reference to the method, not the name of the method.

Comment: Add `@A.val.getter` as a decorator to the `get_val` method on `B`.

Comment: Because `val` is a class attribute and is evaluated when `A` is *constructed*, so it is bound to `A`'s method..

Comment: Also see [Python overriding getter without setter](//stackoverflow.com/q/15785982) and [What is the purpose of Python's property.getter?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14138580) and [How does the @property decorator work?](//stackoverflow.com/q/17330160)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to overload the property in `B`, too:

```
class A():
    def get_val(self):
        print(self)
        raise NotImplementedError

    val = property(get_val)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b_val = "foo\n"

    def get_val(self):
        print(self)
        return self.b_val

    val = property(get_val)
```

or since `get_val` is not really needed, use decorator syntax:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class A():
    @property
    def val(self):
        print(self)
        raise NotImplementedError

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b_val = "foo\n"

    @property
    def val(self):
        print(self)
        return self.b_val

b = B()
print(b.val)
```

Answer (score -2):

The val property is of parent class which is not oveloaded in inerited class. You need to overload it

Comment: Obviously, but why?

Comment: Because that is how it is. It will see for value in child class it will not find then look for it in parent class which will raise exception.

Comment: @advay.umare: nope, try again. Sorry, this is not a helpful answer.